# Is there anyway of implementing neural networks using swift for ios?

Tags: swift3, neural-network, ios10

I have searched a lot and I have not yet been able to find anything that shows any implementation of neural networks using swift. I am planning to build an application using swift that involves the use of neural networks. So i'm wondering if I can get any help regarding this. If there is any documentation regarding neural networks in swift, I would be happy if anybody would provide some reference regarding it.

Comment: There's tons of language agnostic guides out there. Pseudocode should be easily translatable into Swift. Also, asking for resources is offtopic here.

Comment: See WWDC 2016 video [Neural Networks and Accelerate](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/715/).

Answer (score 10):

Of course there is a way. This is my version a Simple Neural Network with backpropagation in Swift

```
import Foundation


public extension ClosedRange where Bound: FloatingPoint {
    public func random() -> Bound {
        let range = self.upperBound - self.lowerBound
        let randomValue = (Bound(arc4random_uniform(UINT32_MAX)) / Bound(UINT32_MAX)) * range + self.lowerBound
        return randomValue
    }
}

public class Layer {

    private var output: [Float]
    private var input: [Float]
    private var weights: [Float]
    private var previousWeights: [Float]

    init(inputSize: Int, outputSize: Int) {
        self.output = [Float](repeating: 0, count: outputSize)
        self.input = [Float](repeating: 0, count: inputSize + 1)
        self.weights = (0..<(1 + inputSize) * outputSize).map { _ in
            return (-2.0...2.0).random()
        }
        previousWeights = [Float](repeating: 0, count: weights.count)
    }

    public func run(inputArray: [Float]) -> [Float] {

        for i in 0..<inputArray.count {
            input[i] = inputArray[i]
        }

        input[input.count-1] = 1
        var offSet = 0

        for i in 0..<output.count {
            for j in 0..<input.count {
                output[i] += weights[offSet+j] * input[j]
            }

            output[i] = ActivationFunction.sigmoid(x: output[i])
            offSet += input.count

        }

        return output
    }

    public func train(error: [Float], learningRate: Float, momentum: Float) -> [Float] {

        var offset = 0
        var nextError = [Float](repeating: 0, count: input.count)

        for i in 0..<output.count {

            let delta = error[i] * ActivationFunction.sigmoidDerivative(x: output[i])

            for j in 0..<input.count {
                let weightIndex = offset + j
                nextError[j] = nextError[j] + weights[weightIndex] * delta
                let dw = input[j] * delta * learningRate
                weights[weightIndex] += previousWeights[weightIndex] * momentum + dw
                previousWeights[weightIndex] = dw
            }

            offset += input.count
        }

        return nextError
    }

}

import Foundation

public class ActivationFunction {

    static func sigmoid(x: Float) -> Float {
        return 1 / (1 + exp(-x))
    }

    static func sigmoidDerivative(x: Float) -> Float {
        return x * (1 - x)
    }

}

import Foundation

public class NeuralNetwork {

    public static var learningRate: Float = 0.3
    public static var momentum: Float = 0.6
    public static var iterations: Int = 70000

    private var layers: [Layer] = []

    public init(inputSize: Int, hiddenSize: Int, outputSize: Int) {
        self.layers.append(Layer(inputSize: inputSize, outputSize: hiddenSize))
        self.layers.append(Layer(inputSize: hiddenSize, outputSize: outputSize))
    }

    public func run(input: [Float]) -> [Float] {

        var activations = input

        for i in 0..<layers.count {
            activations = layers[i].run(inputArray: activations)
        }

        return activations
    }

    public func train(input: [Float], targetOutput: [Float], learningRate: Float, momentum: Float) {

        let calculatedOutput = run(input: input)

        var error = zip(targetOutput, calculatedOutput).map { $0 - $1 }

        for i in (0...layers.count-1).reversed() {
            error = layers[i].train(error: error, learningRate: learningRate, momentum: momentum)
        }

    }

}
```

You can check it with these input data which learns the `AND` logical operator:

```
let traningData: [[Float]] = [ [0,0], [0,1], [1,0], [1,1] ]

let traningResults: [[Float]] = [ [0], [0], [0], [1] ]

let backProb = NeuralNetwork(inputSize: 2, hiddenSize: 3, outputSize: 1)

for iterations in 0..<NeuralNetwork.iterations {

    for i in 0..<traningResults.count {
        backProb.train(input: traningData[i], targetOutput: traningResults[i], learningRate: NeuralNetwork.learningRate, momentum: NeuralNetwork.momentum)
    }

    for i in 0..<traningResults.count {
        var t = traningData[i]
        print("\(t[0]), \(t[1])  -- \(backProb.run(input: t)[0])")
    }

}
```

Comment: This is super cool. How would you abstract the layer into a number of neurons?

Answer (score 5):

[Bender](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Bender) lets you build and run neural nets on iOS. As it uses Metal under the hood, it runs fast and smooth. It also supports running TensorFlow models directly.

Disclaimer: I worked on this project.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at this library - [Swift-AI](https://github.com/collinhundley/Swift-AI), a machine learning library written entirely in Swift and supports iOS and OS X. Another such library is [Swift Brain](https://github.com/vlall/Swift-Brain).

Lots of other useful information on machine learning for iOS can be found [here](http://alexsosn.github.io/ml/2015/11/05/iOS-ML.html).

Also, just as a sidenote, if all you want is to build applications which use machine learning models for iOS, you can always train your models anywhere on Cloud or other system and load them into your application and use them and you need not implement the neural networks in Swift.